# What's the regular expression for pipe-delimited number?

Tags: regex

I want to check that a String is pipe-generated numbers. There should be numbers between pipes.

- Valid Strings examples: `300`, `300|600`.
- Invalid Strings examples: `300||||600`

I tried `^([\d|\d])*$`. However, this still said that `300||||600` is a valid String.

Comment: What about `300|600|900`?

Comment: `^([\d|\d])*$` matches a digit or `|` any number of times, in any order. I recommend going to regex101.com to see what your pattern is doing. https://regex101.com/r/rLV5IC/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, what you want is one number, ie `\d+`, followed by an undetermined number of occurrences of a pipe then a number, which would be `(\|\d+)*` (the pipe is escaped).

As you want it to cover the whole input this would be

```
^\d+(\|\d+)*$
```